# Locking legend in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I locked in the print composition (Druckzusammenstellung) the legend (attachment1).
Then I saved the print composition and opened it (attachment2). But the locked legend is not locked? The changes are gone: polygon b is still part of the legend.

What have I to do to lock the legend?

attachment1:

[image]

attachment2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Locking prevents items from being moved by accident.

I just tried to reproduce the problem, but Print Composer remembered correctly which legend entries had been removed.

If you are using the latest QGIS version, maybe try to deactivate automatic updates of the legend.